# Chrome not recognizing jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, google-chrome

I am trying to use jquery autocomplete plugin in my application.

It works well on IE and FF

Chrome is behaving wierdly and not calling the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/GIM-WebUI/jquery/jquery-latest.js">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/GIM-WebUI/jquery/autocomplete-main.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/GIM-WebUI/jquery/autocomplete.js"></script>
```

I kept alert dialog box in my autocomplete function. Both FF and IE pop up the alert message but not chrome. Am I doing something wrong here?

Its erroring out when I call .autocomplete on some dom element. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the problem is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/GIM-WebUI/jquery/jquery-latest.js">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
                              -^-                                      -^-
```

A `script` tag may *either* have a `src` attribute *or* have code content, not both; from the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#script):

> If there is a [`src`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-src) attribute, the element must be either empty or contain only [script documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#inline-documentation-for-external-scripts) that also matches [script content restrictions](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements).

I suspect you probably want:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/GIM-WebUI/jquery/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

...but only if you really want jQuery not to use the `$` symbol (e.g., you'll always use the `jQuery` symbol instead).

**Off-topic**: Chrome has a good set of tools built-in for helping you diagnose problems. Press Ctrl+Shift+I to see them (or select the Developer Tools from the wrench menu in the upper right-hand corner). You can look for errors in the Console, set breakpoints, walk through code in the debugger, etc...

Comment: I tried the second version even before trying the first one. It did not work.

Comment: As it turned out to be.. chrome is calling the function much before it is loaded.

Comment: @user487925: With the two `script` tags above, respectfully, no it isn't. When the HTML parser runs into a `script` tag, it stops dead in its tracks until that script is loaded and executed (barring use of the `defer` or `async` attributes; see the link above for details). This is not optional and I guarantee you that Chrome is compliant with it. :-) Only once the script from the first `script` tag has been executed does it continue with whatever HTML follows (in this case, another `script` tag). Of course, if you're talking about the combined version, all bets are off with invalid markup.

Comment: @user487925: Of course, if you're talking about it calling some other function earlier than you expect, that would be something else entirely. :-)

Comment: Yes I am talking about calling the functions in this scripts from a completely different function. Apart from that, chrome is throwing the following js errors when loading jquery functions " Object #<an Object> has no method 'find'"; which I got through debug console. any clues (I know its stupid to ask without providing complete js file, here it is http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js)?

Comment: @Chandra: Sorry, I never saw your comment above. I use jQuery, and Chrome, all the time without the issues you're talking about. I suspect you may be trying to do things before the DOM is ready (but it's a shot in the dark), more here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/